# Not able to stop command line process started in thread (in javafx)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, cmd, process

I have started a command line perl process using Java process builder in a thread . When i close my javafx application , perl.exe process keeps running .

I want to close cmd process's input stream and stop that thread .

I have tried below steps already :

1. System.exit
2. process.getInputStream.close()
3. also tried to kill process using java cmd process ( taskkill /f /im perl.exe)

code :

MyRunnable CLASS :

```
    public  class MyRunnable implements Runnable 
    {
       private final int value;
       private Boolean stop = false;
       MyRunnable(int value) 
         {
            this.value = value;
         }
       @Override
       public void run() 
          {
            try
               {
                  ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {   "cmd.exe", "/c", "perl E:\\PerlRunner\\SCRIPTS\\AIRPLANE.pl SP9830A510159222101"});
                  Process pr12=pb2.start();
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                  BufferedReader brq = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr12.getInputStream()));
                  while(brq.readLine()!=null && Variables.flag )
                  {
                    System.out.println(brq.readLine()+" FLAG:IN WHILE"+Variables.flag);
                  }
                  if(!Variables.flag)
                  {
                    pr12.destroy();
                    System.out.println("PROCESS DESTOYED:"+Variables.flag);
                  }

               }
               catch(IOException ee)
               {

               }
               catch(InterruptedException rr)
               {    
               }
             }
           }
```

MAIN CLASS :

TWO BUTTONS :

PLAY :

```
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Variables.flag=true;
            System.out.println("Start");
            MyRunnable n1= new MyRunnable(0);
              Thread t1=new Thread(n1);
              t1.start();
        }});
```

STOP BUTTON :

```
    btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Variables.flag=false;
        }});
```

Variables.flag is static variable defined inside another class .

Perl process :

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    $devices = $ARGV[0];
    $temp = 0;
    $LOGFILE = "E:\\PerlRunner\\times.txt";
    open(LOGFILE) or die("Could not open log file.");
    foreach $line (<LOGFILE>) {           
    if (index($line, "flmTimes") != -1)
    {
    my $result = index($line, "=");
    $temp = substr($line, $result + 1);
    }
    sleep(1);
    }
    for($i=1; $i<=$temp;$i++)
    {
    system("adb -s $devices shell am start -a
    android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS");
    sleep 5;
    system("adb -s $devices shell input tap 200 200");
    sleep 35;
    system("adb -s $devices shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME");
    sleep 3;
    }

    times.txt :
    testTimes=1
    flmTimes=3
    mtcTimes=1
    caseTimes=1
```

Comment: Any comments, does my suggestion work out?

Comment: A hint: you want others to spent their time to help you. So you please take the 5 minutes it takes to properly format/indent **all** of your code; instead of dropping such a (sorry) mess here.

Comment: i solved it . Since java thread starts another process so it is not getting killed after calling destroy . ProcessBuilder pb3 = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "taskkill /im \"perl.exe\" /f"});
                    Process pr13=pb3.start();

Comment: Glad you found the solution yourself. I suspected something like that when I saw your perl code, but forgot about telling you. If you write that up as an answer ... I can't accept that, but would upvote it. Which would allow you to at least upvote my answer, in case you found that to be of value to you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since java thread starts another process so it is not getting killed after calling destroy. The following command gets rid of **all** perl process and thus solves the problem:

```
ProcessBuilder pb3 = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "taskkill /im \"perl.exe\" /f"}); 
Process pr13=pb3.start();
```

Comment: One side note here: understand that this kills **all** your perl processes. So when you have *any* other perl running on that system, that has nothing to do with your application ... that will be killed, too!

Answer (score 1):

The ProcessBuilder [start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) method returns a Process object.

That has a **[destroy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy())** method. Simply call that!

Comment: Hint: you can delete all your comments here then. Good craftsman always keep their stuff in order; same for good coders or SO community members ;-)